# How do I correctly nest a flexbox to achieve a form layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am looking to achieve the following layout:

[image]

Here is how I'm picturing it (with grids):

[image]

- Black bar is the nav (we can ignore this)
- A title and subtitle (purple) - these should be aligned and take up approx 70% of width - I think I've done this
- A form which has 3 columns (should take up 70ish percent of the 70%, I don't want inputs to be too wide)

  - Column 1: Heading  + text pairs
  - Column 2: it will have some icon/character - these must be perfectly aligned
  - Column 3: Heading + input boxes - these must be the same width

Here is my starting HTML:

```css
.title-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: red;
}

.title-item {
  flex-basis: 75%;
}

.data-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: blue;
}

.column-items {
  flex-basis: 70%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.column-1-item {
  background: green;
  flex-grow: 0.5;
}

.column-2-item {
  background: yellow;
  flex-grow: 0.1;
  align-self: center;
}

.column-3-item {
  background: orange;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-container">
  <div class="title-item">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>This is some text</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="data-container">
  <div class="column-items">
    <div class="column-1-item">
      <p>Heading1</p>
      <p>SomeText</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column-2-item">
      <p>--></p>
    </div>
    <div class="column-3-item">
      <p>Heading1</p>
      <input type="text" name="lname">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to expand on this, but no matter what I try, I end up further away from my design making me think there is something wrong with my initial design (and flex understanding). If I add additional 'row', it breaks my layout. I also think my `data-container` is wrongly setup, since this will take up far more space than I want it to

Here is a [code pen](https://codepen.io/jshore/pen/YzzLJmP).

Could someone help get me closer to my design?

Comment: Please try to give some sample output image using MS Paint.. that will help much clear about your requirement.

Comment: I've added an extra image with the alignment that I'm after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would wrap your entire html in a `wrapper` class so that you can get the general layout of the page like so:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title-container">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>
      Subtitle should be aligned with title
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-container">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="column">
      <p>Heading1</p>
      <p>Some Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <p>-></p>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <p>Heading1</p>
        <p>[ input textfield ]</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="column">
      <p>Heading3</p>
      <p>Some Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <p>-></p>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <p>Heading2</p>
        <p>[ input textfield ]</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="column">
      <p>Heading3</p>
      <p>Some Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <p>-></p>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <p>Heading3</p>
        <p>[ input textfield ]</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="column"></div>
      <div class="column"></div>
      <div class="column submit-button">
        <p>[ Button ]</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you can specify the width for the `title-container` and `form-container` with the `width` property. Making each of the `item` classes in the form container have a `display: flex` property lets you format the children `column` classes to have `flex-grow: 1` so they can fill up the available space. The css then looks like:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;  
  align-items: center;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.title-container {
  width: 70%;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.form-container {
  width: 50%;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.column {
  /* flex-grow: 1; */
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.submit-button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Alternately you can remove the `flex-grow: 1` property from the `column` class and add `justify-content: space-between` to the `item` class to get a result similar to your example.
Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/10serna/pen/dyyeERw).

Comment: that's great! Thank you much closer to what I'm looking for. One slight thing, if I modify the text for any heading (in first column) so the length doesn't match lengths it distorts the second column. I don't suppose you would know how to solve this? Thanks again

Comment: Yea as long as your content still fits in the div you can change `flex-grow: 1` to `flex: 1 1 0px` in the `column` class. `flex` is just shorthand for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis`. Although if your content exceeds the limits of its containers it will still move shift the other items. If that is the case then I recommend using CSS Grids where you can specify the amount of columns that can fit into a container and give them equal widths no matter their content.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.data-container` just needs a `flex-direction: column;` because you want the `.column-items` to stack.